# How can I 'fire and forget' a JS function? (do not wait for return)

Tags: javascript

I want to set a JS function running, but not wait for the response. The only way I can think to do it is:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myFunc(); 
},0);
```

But that seems... inefficient at best. Any ideas?

Comment: Better:`setTimeout(myFunc,0)`

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a situation where you'd get any benefit from this that you couldn't get from simply reordering your existing code. Can you provide more information about the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is that inefficient?

Also, don't forget that browser javascript is single-threaded. So, while your function runs, you will implicitly wait for it to return.

(async ajax calls may be an exception here)

Comment: What happens where you're making an asynchronous request ? Isn't it a thread ?

Comment: @ldiqual: that would be an exception. Callback for this request will still run on a main thread.

Comment: Thanks- I guess it makes sense to continue using the setTimeout method.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to look at [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)

Comment: yeah afaik this is the only **true** solution

Comment: Isn't jquery's getScript http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ doing pretty much the same thing?